# How to modify 'docker-compose-local.yml' for it to install all requirements (needed to run Amazon MWAA environment locally)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mwaa

I am running [aws-mwaa-local-runner](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner) in order to run a local Apache Airflow environment (in Docker for Windows).

However, after creating the container using `./mwaa-local-env start`, I repeatedly get the *Broken DAG ModuleNotFoundError*' However, when I check my `/docker/config/requirements.txt` file (see [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/blob/main/docker/config/requirements.txt), although my file has a few more requirements that I need in it). When I compare my `/docker/config/requirements.txt` file with the output of `pip freeze` command run in Airflow container, I can see those requirements I need for my DAGs are missing.

I tried to `pip install` my other requirements in Airflow container but to no avail.

Is there a way to modify [docker-compose-local.yml](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/blob/main/docker/docker-compose-local.yml) file so it installs all of my `requirements.txt` when creating the container (i.e. running the Airflow)?

Is there maybe something I might be missing? Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner . You should run the requirements file located in dags, locally.

pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: Tried that and for some reason that approach didn't work (I'll have to look at it later to see what exactly was causing the issue) but what absolutely worked was adding `RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt` to Dockerfile so Docker installs all requirements when creating the container.

Answer (score 0):

Add your extra requirements to `dags/requirements.txt`, not `docker/config/requirements.txt`. The former is installed every time you start the service, but the latter is only installed when you build or rebuild the image.

Additionally, keeping your added requirements separate is important because you will need to upload the list to your MWAA environment.